# HTML in new Browser Tab or WIndow

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect

In my PHP file, I have a string variable that contains complete HTML code.

```
$content = '<html>
<head>
  <script>--Some javascript and libraries included--</script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <style>--Some Styling--</style>
</body>
</html>';
```

I get this in a loop and now I want this HTML to open in new tab or window of browser. With every iteration, there would be a new Tab or Window. I don't think it is possible on server side so may be some JavaScript need to be concatenated to it.

Comment: To open a webpage, you need to have URL/address of it.. Do you have it ?

Comment: You can create a php page, where it gets POST data and displays it. And in this current php page, you can add an ajax.

Comment: @Rayon Yes I can create a URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In loop, I've created the URL to hit the controller and set the parameters with it and then simple use the following statement.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.open("'. $url .'"); </script>';
```

and In the $url variable, I created the URL and post data in it. That's how, the new tab will open that hits the url and result will be my complete HTML.